# Scrape alibaba's product

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to find a way to scrape information from the [Agriculture growing media](https://www.alibaba.com/catalog/agricultural-growing-media_cid144?spm=a2700.9161164.1.2.57f04e02izIzZ1) page of Alibaba. I am trying to scrape information product_name, company name, min_order, company_name and URL_of_product_image. of all the products.

I want to have the information of one product in one row and continue scraping till the last pagination link.

**Code**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class AliBaba(scrapy.Spider):
    name = ""
    allowed_domains = ["alibaba.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.alibaba.com/catalog/agricultural-growing-media_cid144?spm=a2700.9161164.1.2.57f04e02izIzZ1']

def parse(self, response):
    for products in response.css('div.item-main'):
        item = {
            'product_name': products.xpath('//h2/a/@title').extract_first(),
            'price': products.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/b/text()').extract_first().stripe(),
            'min_order':  products.xpath('//div[@class="min-order"]/b/text()').extract_first(),
            'company_name':products.xpath('//div[@class="min-order"]/b/text()').extract_first(),
            #'url_of_product_image': (What's the query for url) 
        }
        yield item

    # Code follow pagination link
    # What should I do to follow the pegination link?
```

Here is the picture that might gives the clear vision:
[image: Here is the picture that might gives the clear vision.]

Comment: Please specify your question exactly. What are you trying to do that you can't?

Comment: @thirdDeveloper I have edited my post. I gotta extract links until the end of pagination.